# How do I load the Facebook Like button dynamically?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an overlay which fetches content from another page. This page has a Facebook Like button (the HTML5 version).

What's the best way to initialize the Like button on this page? I tried a simple FB.init() on a script page in the loaded page, but that doesn't seem to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it, this works:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```